# how to make the title of the index same row as header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> hi, I wish to have this dataframe:
>
> ```
>   indicator     a     b    c
>         hot     2     2    4
>        cold     3     1    1
> ```
>
> The indicator column is my index, and the indicator row is my header.
>   After i set Indicator column as my index it become:
>
> ```
>                 a     b    c 
>   indicator      
>         hot     2     2    4
>        cold     3     1    1
> ```
>
> Anyone have idea to overcome this problem?

Comment: If i apply this stetement(df.index.name=None), my "indicator" disappear, any idea can still mauntain the indicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just how python handles index and columns. You can't have index name and column names displayed on the same row.